# Bind method call in JavaScript script in Java Scripting

Tags: java, javascript, scripting

Suppose I have a Javascript file

```
function js_main(args){
     /* some code */
     var x = api_method1(some_argument);
     /* some code */
}
```

And I try to run it with `javax.scripting` the usual way

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
engine.eval(...);
```

Now the I'd like to handle the call to `api_method1` in Javascript with my Java class. I'd like to have some kind of mapping/binding of calls i.e. each time the script calls `api_method1(arg)` a method

```
public Object api_method1(Object arg){ ... }
```

(placed in the same class as the engine) would be called.

Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. use `engine.createBindings()` to make a Bindings object;
2. put an object exposing your method into the bindings with some name:

   ```
   Bindings b = engine.createBindings();
   b.put("api", yourApiObject);
   engine.setBindings(b, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
   ```
3. Then in JavaScript there'll be a global "api" object you can call:

   ```
   api.method1( "foo", 14, "whatever" );
   ```

The facility is easy to use, but be careful with what you pass back and forth; it doesn't do that much to convert JavaScript types to Java types.

Comment: What about marshaling data to/from the method (besides the primitives)?

Comment: to pass data back and forth for other than primitive you can use JSON. Your Java code can serialize/deserialize JSON using any JSON library.

Comment: You're pretty much on your own for that. You could serialize to JSON (easy from JavaScript) and then deserialize in Java (less easy, but doable).  Or you can expose various utilities to piece together other Java object types.